# Angular2 compilar y pasar a producción

Tags: angular

Según los tutoriales de internet, para pasar una app a server se debe generar la carpeta dist y queda listo para pasar a producción, sin embargo a mi me sale errores que no encuentra los archivos js (( los cuales si estan )) etc.

¿El servidor debe tener algo especial?, ¿debo instalar npm alli también?

ACTUALIZADO:
con este codigo ya me carga los recursos

```
<script>document.write('<base href="' + String(document.location).replace('index.html', " " ) + '" />');</script>
```

pero me dan errores de promises entre otros

> Error: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state
>   object with UR

Comment: utilizas bower para las dependencias de angular ?

Comment: no, siempre he utlizado solo el angular cli, ya solucione el problema que no cargaba los recursos (post actualizado) sin embargo me salen problemas de promisses y todo eso, la verdad soy muy nuevo en angular  pero tengo presion encima que no se como terminare a la final